# other class static (android)?

Tags: android, class, static

i've problem access other class in android...
i've class databasex (non static) and class CountingFragment (static)....
in CountingFragment i want to access databasex class..but i get result null....
here is my piece of code...

class Databasex

```
 public class DataBasex {
     public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
     public static final String KEY_NAME="namaLokasi";
     public static final String KEY_JENIS="jenis";
     public static final String KEY_KETERANGAN="ket";
     public static final String tanda="DataBasex";

     private static final String DATABASE_NAME="DbPeta";
     private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="lokasi";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

     private DbHelper ourHelper;
     private final Context ourContext;
     private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.i(tanda,"dbHelper-> "+context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tanda,"onCreate-> "+db);
        /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("+
                KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME +" TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_JENIS +" TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_KETERANGAN +" TEXT NOT NULL);");
                */
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tanda,"onUpgrade-> "+db);
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+DATABASE_TABLE);
        //onCreate(db);
    }
}   
public DataBasex(Context c){
    ourContext =c;
    Log.i(tanda,"DataBasex-> "+ourContext);     
}

public DataBasex open() throws SQLException{
    Log.i(tanda,"DataBasex open awal ");
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i(tanda,"DataBasex open-> "+ourDatabase);
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    Log.i(tanda,"[close]");
    ourHelper.close();
}
  }
```

and here is CountingFragment class...

```
  public static class CountingFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    //here myproblem...
    DataBasex con=new DataBasex(getSherlockActivity());

     /**
     *other method
     */
  }
```

i think the code bellow is my problem

```
 DataBase con=new DataBase(getSherlockActivity());
```

if in non-static class i use code bellow and everything is ok....but in static class i can't...why??

```
 DataBase con=new DataBase(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the fact that `Fragment`s need to **first** be attached to an Activity (see the document on [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)s before they can return an Activity. Specifically the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png). First the Fragment is attached to an Activity (and `onAttach()` is called. Then the Fragment can get an Activity instance.

```
DataBasex con=new DataBasex(getSherlockActivity());
```

is in the root of the Class, it will return null - the Fragment does not have an Activity right off the bat.

Change

```
DataBasex con=new DataBasex(getSherlockActivity());
```

So it is:

```
DataBasex con;
```

And add this method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle b)
{
  super.onCreate (b);
  con = new DataBasex(getSherlockActivity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because in Static class there will be No Object, and the access of the methods will be class level access, but in the none-static class there will be an Object of that class, then you should have no null value in the none-static class